# laravel mix : add dependency before run code

Tags: webpack, owl-carousel, laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel webpack . This is my app.js :

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
 el: '#app'
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();
});
```

and `bootstrap.js` :

```
window._ = require('lodash');

window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap-sass');

require('owl.carousel');

window.Vue = require('vue');

window.axios = require('axios');

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.Laravel.csrfToken,
 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

I've added `owl-carousel` library in `bootstrap.js` and  initiated `owl-carousel` in last line of `app.js` .but when i run `npm run watch` and  check app.js (created in `public/js`
)through browser i see `owl-carousel` library is located after `$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel();` . So owl-carousel wont run . how may i manage this issue?

Comment: Can you show your `bootstrap.js` file as well?

Comment: @RossWilson bootstrap.js is added

Comment: In this case the position in your `app.js` doesn't matter as this is just how webpack works. Are you getting an error anywhere? If not, can you describe how it isn't working?

Comment: i get an error says `$` is undefined. i want to know whether webpack  respect to the order of included vendor or not?